# How can I do this effect on the border of a div with CSS?

Tags: html, css, sass

[image]

I need to doing this effect in my div, so i tried with box shadow, but I don´t success.

`[element_html]:hover { box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 10px 10px $blue; }`

Comment: With a fair bit of difficulty. Start with a gradient : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/gradient-borders/

Answer (score 3):

You'll want to work with gradients.  Here's something similar I whipped together for you.

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  background: #222;
}

.module {
  max-width: 250px;
  padding: 1rem;
  color: white;
  border-width: 3px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-image: 
    radial-gradient(
      circle, 
      #26A9FF, 
      rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)
    ) 1 1%;
}
```

```html
<div class="module">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Vero pariatur corporis quaerat voluptatum eos tempora temporibus nisi voluptates sed, exercitationem sequi dolore culpa incidunt accusamus, quasi unde reprehenderit ea molestias.
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! :), It´s very similar